# How to add a center line on a bar plot indicating class midpoints on a barplot in R?

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart

I have the following code in R:

```
bloodgroup <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
xx <- barplot(table(bloodgroup),ylim=c(0, 14))
coords <- as.numeric(table(bloodgroup))
text(x = xx, y = coords, label = coords, 
     cex = 0.8,pos = 3, col = "red")
```

I want instead 1 2 3 4 5 on the x-axis the following labels: 1-7, 8-14, 15-21, 22-28, 29-35. On each bar I want a vertical line in the center indicating the class midpoints. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your vector into a factor and use that factor to label the x-axis.

```
bloodgroup <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
bloodgroup <- as.data.frame(bloodgroup)
bloodgroup <- within(bloodgroup, {
  bloodgroup_factor <- factor(bloodgroup, labels=c('1-7','8-14','15-21',
  '22-28','29-35'))
})
xx <- barplot(table(bloodgroup),ylim=c(0, 14))
coords <- as.numeric(table(bloodgroup$bloodgroup_factor))
text(x = xx, y = coords, label = coords, 
     cex = 0.8,pos = 3, col = "red")
```

To add a center line indicating the midpoints:

```
abline(v=xx)
```